# Sweet Alert Confirm and then perform Delete in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services, sweetalert

So the problem is the following. I've made an AlertService with Sweet Alert. I need to confirm if the user is sure to delete then perform it. Im having troubles with the callbacks context switch eventhough Im using arrow functions and also tried bind(). Here's the code:

**AlertService**

```
/**
 * This is a generic confirmation alert. 
 * @param object the object with properties to be displayed.
 * @return {boolean} if confirmed, true, else null.
 * 
 * For e.g. To generate an warning for example pass 'warning' in type attribute.
 */
confirmAlert(object: any, callback: Function): any {
    swal({
        title: object.title,
        text: object.text,
        type: object.type,
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'OK'
    }).then(function (res) {
        swal({
            title: object.confirmTitle,
            text: object.confirmText,
            type: 'success'
        });
        return callback(true);
    }, function (cancel) {
        swal({
            title: 'Cancelled',
            text: 'Action cancelled',
            type: 'error'
        })
        return callback(null);
    });
}
```

**UsersComponent**

```
/**
 * Deletes the selected user. Displays an alert to confirm.
 * Refreshes the current  users array that is displayed in a table..
 */
deleteUser() {
    let usersToDelete = {
        'users': this.users
    };
    this.alertService.confirmAlert(this.createMessages.alert.delete, (confirm) => {
        if (confirm) {
            this.webService.delete(environment.routes.users.userUrl, usersToDelete).subscribe(res => {
                if (res.status == 200) {
                    this.alertService.okAlert(this.createMessages.alert.deleteSuccess);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    this.refreshUsers();
}
```

The problem is that the object containing the selected users never arrives to the webService. I console.logged everything and came to that problem which I don't know how to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was i had the refreshUsers() outside the callback and I didnt realize it was erasing my **this.users**:

```
/**
 * Deletes the selected user. Displays an alert and refreshes the current array.
 */
deleteUser() {
    let usersToDelete = {
        'users': this.users
    };
    this.alertService.confirmAlert(this.allMessages.alert.delete, (res) => {
        if (res) {
            this.webService.delete(environment.routes.users.userUrl, usersToDelete).subscribe(res => {
                if (res.status == 200) {
                    this.refreshUsers();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}


/**
 * This method is used to refresh the current displayed users table.
 * Select a user and it's index. 
 * Delete it from this.all array.
 * Delete it from this.users array.
 * Call this.getAllUsers() to refresh the array.
 */
refreshUsers() {
    while (this.users.length > 0) {
        this.all.forEach(element => {
            let i = this.users.indexOf(element._id);
            if (i != -1 && this.users.length >= 0) {
                let e = this.all.indexOf(element);
                this.all.splice(e, 1);
                this.users.splice(i, 1);
                this.getAllUsers();
            }
        });
    }
}
```